# How to check if something belongs to a list or not

Tags: plugins

I'm seeking a solution for my website where visitors can verify their membership status by inputting their ID or email. The requirement is for the system to indicate whether they are a member or not, without revealing further details. The member database needs to be entered manually and is not integrated into WordPress. What options are available to achieve this functionality?

Thank you.

Comment: The answer to this is super specific to the solution you picked for membership/lists, there is no one size fits all answer, and you can't take an answer for one service and apply it to another. If you don't have a membership system and are looking for a recommendation then you should ask this on the software recommendations stack and make it clear that you don't currently have a system

Comment: I don't need a membership system. I just want to enter the member list into the website manually. The visitor will have a search box where they can check by email or ID, then it looks as if it matches the list provided manually and returns true (You are a member!) or false (You are not a member!) to the user.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the WordPress Development SE. The community here is trying to curate questions with definitive answers that will help WordPress developers. Plugin suggestion requests are so broad as to be entirely opinion-based making a definitive answer hard or impossible. To be honest, it sounds like you may need a custom solution which should you start and later grind to a halt, might be something we can help with then.